# Which verb (burn/boil/melt) is appropriate to describe that the temperature is high?

Tags: word-choice, metaphors

I'm trying to find an appropriate verb to say that the temperature is high. Actually the question can be split into two parts.

1. Which verb is appropriate to use with a person (e.g. I)?

> It's over 30°C, I'm **burning/boiling/melting**.

2. Which verb is appropriate to use with an object (e.g. the room)?

> It's over 30°C, the room is **burning/boiling/melting**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate metaphor is somewhat dependent on context and tone, but "I'm burning up" is pretty common.

Of course, "I'm melting, I'm melting!" is often borrowed from *The Wizard of Oz* to be used in this sense, even though the "melting" in the story doesn't mean "overheating".